# Is there a way to calculate the win loss record of a schedule with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm very new to pandas and dataframes. I'm playing around with data and I'm trying to figure out a way to calculate a team's record based off of their schedule results. I've tried quite a few things and was looking at iterrows, but was told in the post to stay away from it. So how would you go about calculating the record without using itterrows?

```
def get_team_record(team, last = 0):
    team_df = get_team_schedule(team, last)
    record = {'wins': 0, 'losses': 0}
    return record
```

The get_team_schedule function grabs a specific team's schedule from a set of games. It returns something like this:

|  | Date | Time | Visitor | V_PTS | Home | H_PTS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Wed, Dec 23, 2020 | 8:00p | San Antonio Spurs | 131.0 | Memphis Grizzlies | 119.0 |
| 19 | Sat, Dec 26, 2020 | 5:00p | Atlanta Hawks | 122.0 | Memphis Grizzlies | 112.0 |
| 39 | Mon, Dec 28, 2020 | 7:30p | Memphis Grizzlies | 116.0 | Brooklyn Nets | 111.0 |
| 56 | Wed, Dec 30, 2020 | 7:30p | Memphis Grizzlies | 107.0 | Boston Celtics | 126.0 |

What is the best way to go about calculating the wins and losses of each team?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `idxmax()` of each game to figure out if home or away won. From there, determine the winner and loser with `np.where`, then `concat` the `value_counts()` of each of these columns that we created, and return the sum of each group. Using `.sum(level=0)` is an easy way of doing a `.groupby` and `sum` using the index as a group. The index is the teams after doing the `value_counts().to_frame()` and `concat`:

```
s = df[['V_PTS', 'H_PTS']].idxmax(axis=1)
df['Wins'] = np.where(s.eq('V_PTS'), df['Visitor'],  df['Home'])
df['Losses'] = np.where(s.eq('V_PTS'), df['Home'], df['Visitor'])
df = (pd.concat([df['Wins'].value_counts().to_frame(), 
            df['Losses'].value_counts().to_frame()])
        .sum(level=0))
df
Out[1]: 
                   Wins  Losses
Atlanta Hawks       1.0     0.0
Boston Celtics      1.0     0.0
San Antonio Spurs   1.0     0.0
Memphis Grizzlies   1.0     3.0
Brooklyn Nets       0.0     1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def get_team_record(team, last = 0):
    team_df = get_team_schedule(team, last)
    results = np.where(
        # define these two conditions as a win, otherwise a loss
        ((team_df['Visitor'] == team) & (team_df['V_PTS'] > team_df['H_PTS'])) |
        ((team_df['Home'] == team) & (team_df['H_PTS'] > team_df['V_PTS'])),
        'win', 'loss')
    # sum each outcome and add to dict
    record = {'wins': np.sum(results == 'win'),
             'losses': np.sum(results == 'loss')}
    return(record)
```